# Login to Existing Windows Domain through Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, samba, ldap

So following is my scenario.

I have a domain network and only single machine with Ubuntu. All users are registered on this windows domain.
I have no control over domain network it is maintained by someone else. What is happening is the machine with Ubuntu is being continuous thrown off the network cause the user is not of the windows domain. 
I want to use the existing windows Active Directory or User Directory. I am bad with network terminology and integrate it with Ubuntu.

I have been referring the following guides for the same(Am only allowed to post 2 links):
[ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto)

Now the issues is steps are written to follow and proceed. But it doesnt explain what each does so i cannot predict what can go wrong after doing this in my case. Moreover I am very poor at Networking and its concept. And I do not understand LDAP and SAMBA configuration.

Is there an easier resource or easy to use automation tools to take care of this on Ubuntu. I refer the following for automated tools:
[likewiseopen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/likewiseopen/)
But again how it does at the back is not explained so I cannot predict what can go wrong and it will be difficult to go back.

So now questions are 
1 - Is there a guide that actually explains the steps you are doing ??
2 - Is there a safe practice to follow if we take these steps from online for ease of reverting back what has been done?
3 - Are there any currently active automated tools available for this kind of stuff in ubuntu?
And last but not the least
4 - Is this process really this complex??

Any help and direction for proper resource or proper terminology to use for search would be great help.

Comment: Following are more resources: [ActiveDirectoryBind](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbind-SADMS) ; [SambaKerbos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/Kerberos) ; [SambaIntegration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SambaActiveDirectoryDomainIntegrationScript); [Use of Likewise](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-join-ubuntu-machine-windows-domain)

Comment: likewiseopen is no longer maintained, but PBIS Open is the same product (continued), you might be able to find more information here: https://github.com/BeyondTrust/pbis-open/wiki
But what exactly are you asking? Are you asking us to explain to you the process in technical terms, or are you asking how to logon to an Ubuntu machine with an Active Directory account? I use PBIS open to join Ubuntu machines to the Active Directory and login with AD accounts, but you can also simply install the LDAP tools and configure PAM to use LDAP for login. This won't join make the machine a member of the dom

Comment: I require information in enough detail that if i have to revert back to original state i will be able to do without purging and reinstalling....  The thing is the network has multiple domain controllers and i am not sure whether the policies registered for each user will also work here and how it will work here... So need that kind of info... Also i am begineer or very novice in networking.... So I might also be not aware about other aspects there might be there in configuring the client to be in comply with Domain Controller...

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to have a look at the web site of Samba: [www.samba.org](http://www.samba.org).  You will have there full documentation including access to Windows domains.  In your case, I think this is what you need: [Setting up samba as a domain member](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member)).
Anyway, prepare yourself to have to learn a lot of things, especially if you are novice in networking.

Comment: I am having a feeling that there is no shortcut available i need to go through it all and then experiment and learn... Cause i dont understand certain terms and dont know what a Kerberos is....  So ya i need a read up alot.... I will try this and will get back how this works....